# Yii login from index and ajax login captcha error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, captcha

I would like a user to be able to login to my app at `site/index.php` with an ajax request when the user provides a correct username and password the first time. If username or password is wrong the first time, it shows a captcha then if all inputs are correct don't show captcha error.

This my code:

**loginForm**

```
<?php
 /**
 * LoginForm class.
 * LoginForm is the data structure for keeping
 * user login form data. It is used by the 'login' action of 'SiteController'.
 */
 class LoginForm extends CFormModel
 {
     public $username;
     public $password;
     public $rememberMe;
     public $verifyCode;
     private $_identity;

     /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     * The rules state that username and password are required,
     * and password needs to be authenticated.
     */
     public function rules()
     {
         return array(
            array('username, password', 'required'),
            array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
            array('password', 'authenticate'),
            array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(), 'on' => 'captchaNeed'),
         );
     }

    /**
     * Authenticates the password.
     * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
     */
     public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
     {
          if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
              $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
              if (!$this->_identity->authenticate()) {
                 $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.');
              }
          }
     }

     /**
      * Logs in the user using the given username and password in the model.
      * @return boolean whether login is successful
      */
      public function login()
      {
          if ($this->_identity === null) {
              $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
              $this->_identity->authenticate();
          }

          if ($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
              $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
              Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }
      }
```

**site/index**

```
/**
 * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
 * when ad action is not explicitly requested by users.
 */

 public function actionIndex()
 {
     // set default layout
     $this->layout = 'main';
     $loginModel = new LoginForm;

     if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
         if (isset(Yii::app()->session['captchaNeed'])) {
            LoginModel->scenario = 'captchaNeed';
         }

         if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
             $loginModel->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];

             if ($loginModel->validate() && $loginModel->login()) {
                 echo '<script>window.location= "' . Yii::app()->createUrl('site/dashboard') . '"</script>';

                 unset(Yii::app()->session['captchaNeed']);
                 Yii::app()->end();
             } else {
                Yii::app()->session['captchaNeed'] = true;
                $loginModel->scenario = 'captchaNeed';
             }

             $this->renderPartial('_login', array('model' => $loginModel));
         }
    }

    if (!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
       $this->render('index', array('loginModel' => $loginModel));
    }
 }
```

**siteController actions**

```
public function actions()
 {
    return array(
       'captcha' => array(
           'class' => 'CCaptchaAction',
           'minLenght' => 4,
           'maxLenght' => 4,
           'testLimit' => 1,
           'backColor' => 0x7D287E,
           'foreColor' => 0xFFFFFF,
           'height' => 24,
           'width' => 100,
           'offset' => 1,
       ),
    );
 }
```

**view\site\index**

```
<section class="col-xs-8" id="index-login">
 <?php if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) : ?>
 <div id="login">
    <?php $this->renderPartial('_login', array('model' => $loginModel)) ;?>
 </div>
 <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
     'Login',
      Yii::app()->createUrl('site/index'),
      array(
          'type' => 'post',
          'update' => '#login',
          'data' => 'js:$("#login-form").serialize();
      ),
      array(
          'id'=>uniqid(),
          'class'=>'btn btn-danger',
      )
 ); ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
 </section>
```

**view\site_login**

```
<?php

 /* @var $this SiteController */
 /* @var $model LoginForm */
 /* @var $form CActiveForm  */

 $this->pageTitle  =Yii::app()->name . ' - Login';
 $this->breadcrumbs = array('Login',);
 ?>
 <h1>Login</h1>
 <p>Please fill out the following form with your login credentials:</p>
 <div class="form">
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
     'id'=>'login-form',
      )
 );?>

 <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
 <div class="row">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
     <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    <p class="hint">Hint: You may login with  <kbd>demo</kbd>/<kbd>demo</kbd> or  <kbd>admin</kbd>/<kbd>admin</kbd>.
    </p>
 </div>
 <?php if (CCaptcha::checkRequirements() && $model->scenario == 'captchaNeed'): ?>
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
 <div>
 <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
 <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="hint">Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.
    <br/>Letters are not case-sensitive.
 </div>
 <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
 </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <div class="row rememberMe">
    <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->label($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
 </div>
 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
 </div><!-- form -->
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please explain in more detail what error you are getting, and anything that you have tried to fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: when user first time cant login , captcha apeear in login form , then user insert username and password true and too add captcha true , call captcha wrong i think my rule for captcha have error

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: i have 2 scenario  1. login first time without captcha 2.login with captcha when user enter username or password wrong. in scenario 1 all ok and user can login , in scenario 2 when captcha apeear to form , user try login and cant login even when true enter username password and captcha,. form show error captcha wrong

Comment: I think this line `LoginModel->scenario = 'captchaNeed';` should be `$loginModel->scenario = 'captchaNeed';`

Comment: Why you redirect user using JavaScript code in controller: `echo '<script>window.location= "' . Yii::app()->createUrl('site/dashboard') . '"</script>';`
You should use Yii's function to redirect user: `$this->redirect()` it is more elegant and better.

Comment: MR.M when use ajax request cant use Yii`s function to redirect , I think

Comment: MR.M I use $loginModel->scenario = 'captchaNeed' ;  But other user edit my post and u see LoginModel in lieu of $loginModel